# comparing lists to columns in a txt file

Tags: python, list, comparison

I'm trying to read the 5th column of a file in python. If the third column matches "Plop" I store the third column in a list1, otherwise if the fifth column matches "toto" I store the third column in a list2. Then all I do is I check the lenght of every element in both lists. When I run my code I get this error:

```
if word1 in columns[:4]
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My code is as follow:

```
word1=['Popo']
word2=['toto']
aList1 = list()
aList = list()

for line in open("test.txt"):
    columns = line.split(" ")
 #columns.lookup([toto])
    if word1 in (columns[:4]):
        aList1.insert(columns[:2])
    if word2 in (columns[:4]):
        aList.insert(columns[:2])

#print '\n'.join(aList1)

for entry in aList1:
    try:
        l = len(entry)
        print "Length of", entry, "is", l
    except:
        print "Element", entry, "has no defined length"

for entry in aList:
    try:
        l = len(entry)
        print "Length of", entry, "is", l
    except:
        print "Element", entry, "has no defined length"
```

Comment: And your code doesn't have correct indentation!

Comment: @Arman My code has the correct indentation when it comes to the last 2 for loops, it's just that on stackoverflow I have to physically enter 4 spaces for each line

Comment: @user3022048 just copy/paste the whole thing, highlight it all and click on the `{}` button in the editor, or use ctrl + k

Comment: No , you can use `Ctrl+k` for correct code format!

Comment: My code has been indented now, thanks  !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the **:** in the end, should be:

```
if word1 in columns[:4]:
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it resolves the Syntax error I was having.